# Looking for something to reflect ultraviolet light at extremely low wavelengths

Tags: materials, thermodynamics, building-physics

I have been working on a product that involves the reflection of low wavelengths of UV light (200-250nm). However, I have not come across many materials that are able to do so and the high-reflectivity mirrors I come across are extremely expensive. What mirrors would be able to reflect UV light at such wavelengths at around a 50-75% reflectivity rate?

Answer (score 1):

An aluminium coating have a higher than 80% reflectivity in the wavelengths you want. Source: https://www.layertec.de/en/capabilities/coatings/metallic

If you put the coating behind glass like in a common mirror, make sure to not use glass that absorbs UV lighting. Maybe you can use an aluminium coating without any glass in front.